# Use $n$ different integers with $+$ or $-$ to make equations, find out the unused numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithmic-randomness

I am just a normal Chinese student and I can't communicate well with English. The question is there are $n$ different integers, we can use $+$ or $-$ to make equations to let the result be zero and in one equation a number will be used no more than once.

The algorithm is to find all the numbers in $n$ integers that can't be used in  equations. For example, $n=4, 2, 3, 5, 11$ and $11$ is the output. It is an NP question, but when the sum of integers is small we can use a dynamic program. But I don't know how to have a $O(n\cdot S)$ or $O(n \log n \cdot S)$ algorithm. Maybe this question is simple but it puzzles me for a long time.

Comment: I am unsure whether this is on-topic here, but apart from that the problem is difficult to understand; you write "for example ,n=4, 2 3 5 11 11is the output" why does 11 appear twice in this sentence? and $2+3+5-10=0$, so why are 2 3 5 not allowed when $n=4$?

Comment: @Carlo, I think OP is saying, if the input is $\{2,3,5,11\}$, then the output is $11$, because $11$ can't be used (with $2,3,5$) to make zero – but $2,3,5$ can be used, as $2+3-5=0$.

Comment: So I think the question can be stated this way: given a finite set of distinct integers, find an efficient way to determine which (if any) of the integers in the set can't be expressed as a sum/difference of some others in the set?

Comment: A partial case of this is a knapsack problem, so no easy solution is to be expected.

Comment: I have cleaned it up. I think $lg$ is meant to denote $\log_2$, but then I'm not sure why it's $nnS$ instead of eg $n^2S$. It's possible $lgn$ is meant to be $\ln$, but I just don't know.

Comment: [And](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384760/use-n-different-intergers-or-to-make-equations-find-o-numbersut-the-unused#comment980137_384760) of course $\log n^2 S$ is asymptotically the same as $\log n S$, so that it seems unlikely that the distinction would be made when describing the asymptotics …. // After @DavidRoberts's great improvements in the question body, I tried to clean up the title a bit, but am also voting to close unless the asker comes back to clarify.

Comment: @LSpice I'm not sure I can figure out what the second half of the title is trying to say, which of course given the language forced on the OP, is no judgement on the actual post. But it would be nice to get some clarification.

Comment: Hmm, I believe "find o numbersut the unused numbers" should be "find out the unused numbers", which makes sense relative to the body of the question, even if it could be better put.

Comment: sorry for my poorly English that i can't explain the question well.一.the question means exactly by@Gerry Myerson, but the sum of all is very small.二. in China lg means log10(). lognnS is nlognS......

Comment: 三.if we only want the all numbers  that can be showed( even not in the set),we can use dp or Generating function to get a O(nS) algorithm( like the Weights QUESTION,1 3 9 three weights can show 1 to 13),but for me it's hard to distinguish if the wanted numbers use themselves. Easily we can run n times 
n-1 situations,but the O() will be n^2S,and there are other ways to simplify.i want the whether the lower bound will be O(nS) or O(nlognS) and the algorithm,and i hope no hard data @GerryMyerson@LSpice@David Roberts might the QUESTION is easy ,but for me is too hard...

Comment: You can only alert one person per comment, sheny.

Comment: Thank you professor@Gerry Myerson

Comment: It's not my area of expertise, but I hope the question is now easier to answer since your clarification

Comment: Also, I think you have to leave a space before the at-sign for the notification to work.

Comment: I have voted to close as unclear. Shenyuantao, I suggest using translation software to see what this says when translated into Chinese; when the English is clear, the auto-translated version should be mostly clear too.

Comment: @MattF. OK, Professor.And i will translate better.

Comment: @MattF. OK, Professor.And i will translate better.